# Confused about database size impact of nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I'm doing bulk inserts of 6 tab-seperated txt files, each about about 1gb uncompressed. (some are 4 million rows)

I expected this to be no problem for MS-SQL BULK-INSERT but apparently there is a 4GB /10GB mdf file size limit depending on the license (express 4 / payed 10) and I'm crossing that limit during my bulk inserts

This database is using a lot of **nvarchar(max)** columns. Does this explain why i'm going over the file size limit? Here's an example of my insert

```
BULK INSERT DUMP1TableName FROM 'c:\usr1\myserver.be\www\myproject\somefolder\data\DUMP_1.txt' WITH  ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',CODEPAGE ='1252',FIRSTROW =2,ROWS_PER_BATCH =10000)
```

Is there any way to fit 6GB uncompressed text inside a sql database of 4GB? unicode is a must here.

Comment: The 4GB/10GB is difference between versions not licenses. The 2012 express edition (or 2008 R2 express) can store up to 10GB of data per DB. The 4GB limit is for 2005/2008 express so downloading the latest version may allow you to do what you want (though still sounds like it may not be possible if when you say 6 GB you in fact mean 12 GB because of double byte storage)

Comment: We use SQLServer 2008 (paid). We have one DB that is 46GB.  Sounds like you're using 'express'...  My experience has been that the table/index/unicode overhead has always at least doubled the size of the imported text file.  Do the columns need to be `nvarchar`, or can you use `varchar`?

Comment: varchar is not really an option we're working internationally and names could technically be chinese  or arab. 

I'm reading everywhere that I should partition my data accross multiple databases, but i'm really afraid this will break my entire Entity framework architecture. 

Going for R2 seems like the only viable option right now, or either buying the payed license.

Comment: I can confirm that moving to R2 works fine for > 4GB